Equals method with casting of generic parmeterized class
I am using Java 21.
I am trying to write an equals method for MyClass<T>, which defines a nested class MyNested<T> extends Comparable and a getNested() method which returns the instance of the MyNested<T> class which is defined during the construction and an instance of MyClass<T>.
I am unclear how to do this properly.
If I do:
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if ((obj == null) || (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())) return false;
        MyClass<?> other = (MyClass<?>) obj;
        return this.getNested().compareTo(other.getNested()) == 0;
    }

I get the compile error:
java: incompatible types: MyClass.MyNested<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to MyClass.MyNested<T>
This happens because the MyNested.compareTo(...) method wants an object of type MyNested<T>, but other.getNested() returns an object of type MyNested<?>.
If I do:
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if ((obj == null) || (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())) return false;
        MyClass<T> other = (MyClass<T>) obj;
        return this.getNested().compareTo(other.getNested()) == 0;
    }

My IDE complains:
Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.object' to 'MyClass<T>'
which I can make go away by adding
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
on the line before the cast, but I am not certain that this is the correct thing to do since I do not believe that the this.getClass() != obj.getClass() check on the previous line guarantees that the generic types are the same, only that the classes are the same.
What is the correct what to write the equals method in this case?

Whether the cast is safe depends on how MyNested implemented Comparable. Please show a complete, [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into my IDE and reproduce the issue.

It sounds like the fundamental problem is that the nested class can only be compared to nested classes with the same type argument, when you need to be able to compare nested instances of any type.

Actually, why even use compareTo on the nested type instead of equals? That would be the most straightforward solution, assuming that equals is implemented correctly on the nested class. If not, it should be: equals and compareTo should always return consistent results or else you’ll inevitably end up with weird bugs.

Just use equals (or the Objects.equals utility method) instead of compareTo, e.g.:
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    MyClass<?> other = (MyClass<?>) obj;
    return Objects.equals(getNested(), other.getNested());
}


Yes, this is a much better solution. Thank you!

@AmateurLinguist If my answer does actually answer your question then can you mark the answer as Accepted?

Hi, @jon-hason. Sorry, I am new, and did not know to do this. Done! And, thank you again!
